# Converting decimals to hexadecimals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, hex, decimal

I really want to work with hex values in TTN but I haven't found a way to get the 'frm_payload'. So now I use a default script to convert it to decimals but I can't find a solution for turning it back into a hex value. I think the solution is probably quite simple but I keep overlooking it, so maybe someone can help me and give a push in the right direction.

This is my code, it reads the payload and turns the first hex value (7C) to a decimal number (124):

```
   var decoded = {};
    
    function Decoder(bytes, port) {
      if (port == 1) {
        decoded.test = bytes[0];
      }
      return decoded;
    }
```

And this is the output I get:

```
{
  "test": 124
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert a number to a hexadecimal string with:

```
hexString = yourNumber.toString(16);
```

And reverse the process with:

```
yourNumber = parseInt(hexString, 16);
```

Comment: If I try that, I get an error. "Could not convert struct value [object Object] to map[string]interface {} for field Data: could not convert [object Object] to map[string]interface {}" Is there another way to convert it?